# How to stop a running service using broadcast receiver in android

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

I think  there is a simple problem in my code but I couldn't figure it out. I have a HeaderService which shows a bubble popup over some particular apps. Now what I want is stop that service when user presses Home key or Back key using BroadCastReceiver. Please take a look at my code and suggest me some solution.
Thanks in Advance!!

This is my Receiver class

```
public class PopupClosingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Context con) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) con.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (HeaderService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(isMyServiceRunning(context)){

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, HeaderService.class);
        context.stopService(serviceIntent);

    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".PopupClosingReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: what's the error? what is your problem please shared what you tried.

Comment: The thing is, HeaderService should stop running when I press Home key but it's not. Its keep on showing bubble popup  even after I close that particular app.

Comment: its not stopping is not the concern when you are pressing the back button what happens? do you know how to apply logs or do debug does your broadcast's gets fired if it gets fired then why its not stopping. These are the simple things you need to consider.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that an `<intent-filter>` with `<category>` would cause your `BroadcastReceiver` to get triggered?

Comment: I am not sure about using <intent-filter> with category Home. That's why i am asking whether it's a correct approach or not.

Comment: That `<intent-filter>` will not work. There is no way (that I know of) to get notified whenever the user presses the HOME button. Do you have an `Activity` running in the foreground when you are trying to trap the HOME button? I don't understand your complete problem, please clarify.

Comment: I make my question a bit more clear. I have a service which runs in background all the time. This service shows a popup when user opens (let's say  MakeMyTrip). Now i want to close that popup when user closes MakeMyTrip app by pressing Home-key or Back-key. To capture these key-press events I am using BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the service at any time because the service is registered in the system ("Thread") wait to be activated or stops   at any time.

Example:

```
 public class Phonecall extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent song_wweather=  new Intent(context,Song_weather.class); //service class
  if(intent.getAction()=="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"){

TelephonyManager telephonyManager =
        (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

PhoneStateListener callStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
    {
        if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
            context.stopService(song_wweather);
        }


        if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){
            context.startService(song_wweather);
        }
    }
};
telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);



}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     public void sendSMS { 

     

ActivityManager am=   (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService( Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );

 List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> rs = am.getRunningServices(50);

String message = null; 

for (int i=0; i<rs.size(); i++) {
    ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo rsi = rs.get(i);
    Log.i("Service", "Process " + rsi.process + " with component "
```

Comment: Hello, you could improve this answer by adding some text explaining it. Also the formatting is off.